# What is wrong with this line of Swift iOS Code?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, nsdictionary

I have created an iOS app using Swift and everything is working fine and dandy on the simulator. I get no errors or crashes at all, but when I submit my app to put up on the app store Apple rejects it and lets me know that it crashes when the user makes a selection. I cannot recreate this error/crash. I took the crash logs and symbolicated them. This line of code came up as the culprit for the crashes:

```
linksToPass =  getLinks(season) as [String:[String]]
```

This line is trying to store the resulting Dictionary from the getLinks() function I created. It for sure is getting a dictionary and if there is no dictionary to send back I create a dictionary which has error information in it, so it is for sure returning a dictionary in that format no matter what. Seeing as I cannot recreate the crash, I am just trying to error check this line of code in any way possible so it does't crash when I resubmit to Apple.

I tried checking if the resulting dictionary was nil like so:

```
if(getLinks(seasons) != nil){
  linksToPass =  getLinks(season) as [String:[String]]
}
```

This is not valid though, and XCode lets me know that UInt8 is not compatible with NSDictionary or something of that nature.

I then fixed that line and changed it to this:

```
if(getLinks(seasons) != ["":[""]]){
   linksToPass =  getLinks(season) as [String:[String]]
}
```

I am just not sure if this is even a good way to check for errors. I was wondering if there were any suggestions on how I may go about making sure this line does not fail and result in a crash. Thank you very much.

EDIT:
Here is my getLinks() function if that helps add more info to the problem:

```
var season = ""
let hymn_links = Hymn_Links()
func getLinks (nameofseason:String) -> NSDictionary
{
    switch (nameofseason)
    {
        default:
            return ["Maps Not Found": []]
    }
}
```

EDIT #2:

This is my updated getLinks() function with the use of optionals.

```
func getLinks (nameofseason:String) -> NSDictionary?
{
    switch (nameofseason)
    {
        default:
            return nil
    }
}
```

Also in my statement of linksToPass I changed it to:

```
if let links = getLinks(season) as? [String:[String]]
    {
        linksToPass =  links
        hymnnames = [String] (linksToPass.keys)
    }
```

Comment: You should also post the method you are calling getLinks() and how you declare seasons

Comment: You are using Swift, Swift has Optionals for just this reason. Use them.

Comment: I added the getLinks() function to my post. Hopefully that helps make the issue more clear. Thanks for the suggestion Leonardo.

@Zaph, I am relatively new at swift so forgive my ignorance of the topic. I remember reading about that. It has to do with adding a "?" or "!" correct?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that when one chooses a language one should use the language in the manner it was designed. Swift was designed wilt Optionals in mind, can't really ignore them, use them. Ignoring them will cause crashes.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Thank you for bringing them to my attention. I will definitely be using them from now on.

Answer (score 2):

There are some known issues with the Swift optimiser. Some people have resorted to shipping with debug builds.

My suggestion would be to test with an optimised build to see if you can reproduce it. You can then try shipping a debug build to the App store.

**General Code Comments**

Why are you returning an NSDictionary rather than a Swift dictionary anyway? Without knowing the contents and creation method for your hymn_links object I can't be sure how good it is.

I would avoid `as` casts until Swift 1.2 and stick to using `as?` and then handling the nil case. At least in your "Edit 2" a nil will cause a crash as nil cannot be cast to `[String:[String]]` although `[String:[String]]?` should be possible.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, would my edit 2 be correct now? Or should it be as? [String:[String]]?

Comment: It looks OK now. It casts to `[String:[String]]` if it is possible and returns nil if it isn't. The result of the `as?` cast is  `[String:[String]]?` because the cast may fail. The `if let` then kicks and unwraps the optional result to bind the `[String:[String]]` to `links`. If you cast to  `[String:[String]]?` the result of the `as?` would be  `[String:[String]]??` and the `if let` would only unwrap the outer layer leaving links as having the type  `[String:[String]]?` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: This is very complicated. Thank you for letting me know that my current code is correct, but I'm definitely going to need to spend some time studying and trying to wrap my head around optionals. I appreciate your time and help Joseph

Answer (score 1):

Can you guarantee that all of the items returned by the switch statement will **never** under any circumstances be nil? If not `getLinks` should return an Optional.

Note that is is virtually impossible for `getLinks` to know that one of the items will never be nil and in Swift un-handed nils are a crash waiting to happen. Unless all these methods correctly handle nil.

Return an Optional and handle that in the statement that calls `getLinks`.

Languages handle nils differently, Objective-C handles them rather well, Java and Swift by crashing. But Swift has a mechanism to handle nils without crashing: Optionals, use it.

Comment: Thank you again Zaph. I have updated my original post and put my newly fixed code under "Edit #2". Would this suffice to not crash? And am I using optionals correctly as to how you were suggesting? Thank you Zaph, I appreciate the feedback and advice.